# Create Mockito Array of some Object type

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I need to provide some mock object array of this type "TypeA[]".

I am trying to do this but getting classcastexception:

```
List mockList = Mockito.anyListOf(TypeA.class);

when(someService.create(Mockito.any(TypeB.class), (TypeA[])mockList.toArray())).thenReturn(1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message told you clearly :

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

The method call to object returned by *Mockito.anyListOf* can only inside stubbing or verification .

you can simply do that to mock array :

```
when(mockTest.create(any(TypeB.class), any(TypeA[].class))).thenReturn(1);
```